# how can we define side by side paragraphs with TeX primitive commands

Tags: tex-core, minipage, sidebyside

I know the LaTeX environment `minipage`, but I would know how to define two side by side paragraphs with TeX primitive commands.
because the inconvenient with `minipage` is that does not handle breaking page.
By the way, how is "minipage" defined in tex?

I tried this, which obviously did not work:

```
\begingroup
\leftskip0em
\rightskip.8\linewidth
\lipsum
\par
\endgroup
\hfill
\begingroup
\leftskip.5\linewidth
\lipsum
\par
\endgroup
```

Comment: minipage is essentially just `\vbox`  with `\hsize` inside the box set to the specified width. You could clearly do that in tex primitives which would answer your question but as it would have the same issue that boxes do not break over a page, I am not sure it actually helps your real (unstated) use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tex primitive `vtop` as shown in this plain tex file which only uses primitives (apart from the macro `\bye`) to end)

[image]

```
\noindent\vtop{\hsize=5cm
one two three 
one two three 
one two three 
one two three
one two three
one two three

abc abc
abc abc
abc abc
abc abc
abc abc
abc abc
abc abc
}
\vtop{\hsize=7cm
right hand text right hand text
right hand text right hand text
right hand text right hand text
right hand text right hand text
right hand text right hand text
right hand text right hand text
}

\bye
```

If your actual question is how to make side by side columns allowing page breaking, then that is a rather different question and unrelated to tex primitives, in particular it would need to interface to the format's page breaking macros so be rather different for latex or plain tex. It is hard to tell which you format you are targetting as tagged tex-core but also minipage (which is latex-specific)  For latex you should look for packages such as parallel designed for parallel columns.

Comment: O, thanks for your answers. Yes, i would like to know how to proceed to handle breaking pages with vtop, in tex-core syntax. Any documentation at this point ? I'm sure it exists.

Comment: @ThomasLeger sorry it doesn't really mean anything to say core syntax here,as I tried to explain in the answer any solution to that would be unrelated to the question as written and need a lot of non-core macros interfacing to whatever page breaker you are usjng so the latex output routine if you are using latex. have you tried the packages that provide side by side texts, what issue do you have with them?

Comment: yes, but how does 'parallel' allow page break. i've tried this package, but it's too rigid, and i can't insert lines the way i want. i'd rather do it myself, so that it's clearer. but i can't figure out how to allow page break of a group x)

Comment: you can't simply allow a page break, there are various things you can do: you can set each column as a "page" then re-assemble each pair of columns into one real page in the output routine, or you can measure how much space is left on the page then `\vsplit` each of the column boxes to that length and re-assemble a row with a pair of boxes, then the page break  then start collecting teh next pair of boxes. or you can (with some restrictions on content) dissa-semble the saved column boxes and re-assemble the lines line by line so allowing page break at any point.....

Comment: ... all of these will take a few hundred lines of code so asking how to do it with tex primitives doesn't really help, and all will have the kind of restrictions you see in other implementations of this.